# CDK rds database cluster and assigning existing security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, aws-security-group

I'm using AWS CDK rds.DatabaseCluster to create a new RDS Postgres SQL cluster. It's working fine.

However, I can't find an existing way to assign an existing security group to this cluster for security. Has anyone done it before?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an existing security group by using the following:

```
const securityGroup = SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(this, 'SG', 'sg-12345', {
   mutable: false
});
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.SecurityGroup.html

Comment: Hi There. That's just getting the exiting security group. Now that I have it, how do I attach it to my newly created   rds.DatabaseCluster?   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_rds/DatabaseCluster.html

Comment: You can assign it to DatabaseInstance not to DatabaseCluster. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.DatabaseInstance.html#securitygroups